# Why does h2o.gbm generate different models when rebuilding with only non-trivial importance features

Tags: r, h2o, gbm

Unfortunately I can't reproduce this problem on the open source data that I've just experimented with (I can't provide the original data on which I have a problem as it's commercially sensitive). However, ...

I have built a h2o.gbm() on a dataset with a set of parameters and seed set to 1. If I take the features for which feature importance > 0, and then build a new gbm (everything exactly the same as before, but slightly less features specified), then I obtain a very different model!

How can this be?

I will look to try and provide something re-producable, but in the meantime any insight would be appreciated. Happy to clarify the problem if I've not been articulate enough.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: I'm using h2o R package version ‘3.20.0.2’

Answer (score 0):

Never mind - I've found the problem : column sampling is the culprit!

Obviously this isn't a bug, but something to be aware of.